# Testing a Raspberry pi image in a docker container

Tags: image, docker

I would like to make a smoke test of a Raspberry Pi image in a docker container.

I am building the image using packer.io and the build-arm-image plugin in a gitlab pipeline inside a docker container. This packer plugin use qemu to run an existing arm image, run command inside it and save the resulting image.

I have tried to reload the image generated, but when trying to check if the systemd services which I had enabled were available, I got an error that systemd could not run in docker containers (something about dbus not being available)

Is there another way to run this image in a docker container (to be run in my pipeline) and test if the services are running and if the website/api is available?

Comment: *"I would like to make a smoke test of a Raspberry Pi image in a docker container"* -> I presume you understand you can't do that on a non ARM system; if so you should make it clear you are testing the image **on a pi**.  If not: Docker does not emulate hardware, so your image must be compiled for the same platform as the host.

Comment: The goal with docker is quite opposite what you envision. Virtualization (VMware, HyperV, QUEMU and so on) is what you aim for so check out ESXi for Raspberry Pi, https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/get-vmware-on-raspberry-pi/

Comment: What I have been doing was to use packer.io in docker. Packer (with the build-arm-image provisioner) run an arm image using qemu (will update question for clarification) This is how I am building an arm image in a docker container, but I fail to understand why the same trick does not work to run systemd...

Comment: @goldilocks the elements I would like to test are not linked to the hardware. Those are more software components (script running every n minutes deleting files for example). I am not sure if some  Systemd services are hardware dependent making all of it disabled in qemu...

Comment: Unless you are making use of peripherals like the I2C bus or the camera, etc.  you should be able to run an image in qemu.  Which, WRT "is there another way", why don't you just run the image w/o docker. ie., just use qemu?

Comment: @goldilocks I am doing it in docker, because it is part of my continuous Integration pipeline running on gitlab. In order to use gitlab infrastructure the pipeline needs to run in a docker container. The idea would be to make sure that the main components (web Server, systemd services etc) are properly configured before flashing the image and running it on my pi... I was also expecting this to work as it does not use hardware, but I get this error that systemd is missing dbus, so I am afraid I did not understand one part of the problem.

Comment: If you are going to deploy this on the pi with docker, then just use docker w/ a Debian buster image (actually there's an x64 version of RpiOS too) and do it all that way -- you don't have emulate the Pi at all.  If you *aren't* going to use docker on the pi but instead want to copy the image created with docker onto a card, I'd say that is not a good way to deploy a system: You should either run a container on the Pi host with your service, or else use some kind of provisioning/auto-configuring (ansible, puppet, chef, etc) ->

Comment: -> Literally building an entire binary image is very very *brittle* and libel to cause you all kinds of hassle and headache (such as your current problem).  If you are sure there is no way out of it because of your other requirements (gitlab pipeline, about which I know nothing), then keep in mind that by doing something that is (ostensibly) obtuse, you've significantly reducing the help that will be available to you.  You should probably pursue this somewhere with more of a userbase focussed on Packer or Gitlab.

Comment: Thank you for the in depth explaination!

Answer (score 1):

The goal with docker is quite opposite what you envision.

From https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/containers/containers-vs-vms

- Containers are typically measured by the megabyte. They don’t package anything bigger than an app and all the files necessary to run, and are often used to package single functions that perform specific tasks (known as a microservice). The lightweight nature of containers—and their shared operating system (OS)—makes them very easy to move across multiple environments.
- VMs are typically measured by the gigabyte. They usually contain their own OS, allowing them to perform multiple resource-intensive functions at once. The increased resources available to VMs allow them to abstract, split, duplicate, and emulate entire servers, OSs, desktops, databases, and networks.

So virtualization (VMware, HyperV, QUEMU and so on) is what you aim for so check out ESXi for Raspberry Pi, https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/get-vmware-on-raspberry-pi/ that could be what you look for.

Comment: Note that while it is not the norm with docker, a container can contain an entire OS and be used much the same as a system in a true VM.  "Entire" except for the kernel, because all containers run on the host kernel (which is why by implication they all must target the same platform).  I mention this in case there is any confusion on the part of the OP ("Oh but I did use a complete system image..." -- no, not quite).

Comment: I agree kind of @goldilocks, An analogue is, you can use a spade to cut a cake with, but the goal for a spade is to dig dirt ;-)

Comment: @MatsK thanks for your answer. As I have now corrected in the question, I am using qemu (in packer) in docker. What I not understand is how much of the kernel of the system running on qemu is shared with the other layers (docker, host)...